# AWS ELB and managing certificates. HTTPS call add domain name to API URL call

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, aws-certificate-manager

some background.

Front end(REACTJS) hosted on HostGator. I have a purchased domain name (domain.com) Code holds api url for its GET PUT and so on of ELB("https://name-id.area.elb.amazonaws.com/")

Back end hosted on Elastic Beanstalk (war file - tomcat) has a load balancer with two listeners http and https which has the certificate of my domain which I verified by email.

calling the api with **http**:name-id.area.elb.amazonaws.com/. causes no issue and will direct to the real api and return me the results.

however if I make a call using **https** of the same url it fails. The api call becomes https:domain.com/name-id.area.elb.amazonaws.com/bla/bla/params which does not exist.

I have no idea how to fix this. All this to make my website work with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you have created two listener to your ELB http and https respectively. http request works fine.

Make sure your listener are associated to the target group which are able to handle https request.

your target group should have at least one instance which will handle https request. you can do it while creating the target group.  Hope this was helpful and you could narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have checked and my target groups are unused. I am currently trying to figure out how to use them. Also any idea why the url becomes like i shown above is that related to target groups also?

Comment: @SHAHEERAWAN so i guess we have narrowed down the issue. 
Make sure your https listener have associated to target group which handle https traffic

Comment: okay so i was using the classic load balance and I couldn't attach groups to it. I did have listeners attached onto hearing out for https. also health checks fails when i set it on HTTP or HTTPS but passed on TCP. I created a new loadblancer and attached groups and health checks are failing on https? any guide?

Comment: @SHAHEERAWAN Please try using Application Load Balance

Comment: okay I am trying that and the status for my port 80 with http is healthy but port 443 with https gives me  unhealthy with code 502. Thanks for the help btw